# How to exclude a number from a range in python?

Tags: python

I'm new to coding, and I wrote a program using a for loop and a range to check if a number from that range is odd or even. However I want to exclude the number 0

```py
    for num in range (0, 11):

      if num %2 == 0:

         print (num,' is an even number!')

      else:
         print (num,' is an odd number!')
```

I expected the output of all the numbers but not the 0.
could someone help me?

Comment: use `range(1, 11)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As answers have already mentioned, `range(1, 11)` will produce `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10` as requested. However you can exclude specific numbers by doing:

```py
all_numbers = range(0, 11)
exclude_set = {0}  # a set containing the value 0
numbers = (num for num in all_numbers if num not in exclude_set)
```

This could be useful if you have a set of numbers that you know are wrong, but otherwise have a contiguous range.

```py
"""Represent retail stores in a chain"""

store_numbers = range(1, 51)

# stores 14, 17, and 32 have been closed, so
closed_stores = {14, 17, 32}

valid_stores = (store for store in store_numbers if store not in closed_stores)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude 0 then change your range to (1,11). The way range works is the lower limit is inclusive where as upper limit is exclusive.

Docs to read more about range: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range

On an unrelated note, if your lower limit is 0, you need not include the lower limit and write it as range(11) which is same as range(0,11).

Answer (score 1):

Range is inclusive of the first parameter, but does not include the second parameter. The first number in range should be the number you want to start with.

Change your code to

```
for num in range(1, 11):

    if num % 2 == 0:

        print(num, ' is an even number!')

    else:
        print(num, ' is an odd number!')
```

Comment: *but does not include the second value* - so in your example the range will not include 2? I think you meant to say it is exclusive of the last value.

Comment: He probably meant the 2nd parameter, but it could be better presented.